# Frequency Bag - getFrequencyOf(aData)

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

Having Trouble with the method getFrequencyOf(aData), returns zero for every element I am searching for in the Test code...here's my code if anyone can point me to what I'm doing wrong that would be much appreciated

```
public class FrequencyBag<T>
{
    // TO DO: Instance Variables
    private Node firstNode;
    private int numberOfEntries;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Constructs an empty frequency bag.
     */
    public FrequencyBag()
    {
        // TO DO
        firstNode = null;
        numberOfEntries = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Adds new entry into this frequency bag.
     * @param aData the data to be added into this frequency bag.
     */
    public void add(T aData)
    {
        // TO DO
        if(numberOfEntries != 0){
            Node newNode = new Node(aData);
            newNode.next = firstNode.next;
            firstNode = newNode;
            numberOfEntries++;
        }
        else{
            Node newNode = new Node(aData);
            firstNode = newNode;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Gets the number of occurrences of aData in this frequency bag.
     * @param aData the data to be checked for its number of occurrences.
     * @return the number of occurrences of aData in this frequency bag.
     */
    public int getFrequencyOf(T aData)
    {
        // TO DO
        int counter = 0;
        Node currentNode = firstNode; 
        for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfEntries; i++)
        {
            if(currentNode.data.equals(aData))
            {
                counter++;
                System.out.println(counter);
            }
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
        return counter;

    }

    /**
     * Gets the maximum number of occurrences in this frequency bag.
     * @return the maximum number of occurrences of an entry in this
     * frequency bag.
     */
    public int getMaxFrequency()
    {
        // TO DO
        Node currentNode = firstNode;
        int currentFrequency = 0;
        int maxFrequency = currentFrequency;
        for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfEntries; i++)
        {
            currentFrequency = getFrequencyOf(currentNode.data);
            if(currentFrequency > maxFrequency)
            {
                maxFrequency = currentFrequency;
            }
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }
        return maxFrequency;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the probability of aData
     * @param aData the specific data to get its probability.
     * @return the probability of aData
     */
    public double getProbabilityOf(T aData)
    {
        // TO DO
        int num = getFrequencyOf(aData);
        double probability = num / numberOfEntries;
        return probability;
    }

    /**
     * Empty this bag.
     */
    public void clear()
    {
        // TO DO
        firstNode.next = null;
        firstNode.data = null;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the number of entries in this bag.
     * @return the number of entries in this bag.
     */
    public int size()
    {
        // TO DO
        return numberOfEntries;
    }


    private class Node
    {
        private T data;
        private Node next;
        public Node (T a)
        {
            data = a;
            next = null;
        }
        public Node(T a, Node n)
        {
            data = a;
            next = n;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I did not read the full code, because there is a mistake in the add method, which probably causes the problem you face:

```
Node newNode = new Node(aData);
newNode.next = firstNode.next; //firstNode.next is null!
firstNode = newNode;
```

When you add the first node, it's pointing to a null node (its next value is null).

Then, when you add a second node, as in the line above, your new head of the list points to the next node of the previous head, which is always null. So, your list always has only one node, the `firstNode`. To fix that, change the above lines as:

```
Node newNode = new Node(aData);
newNode.next = firstNode;
firstNode = newNode;
```

OR (using the second constructor):

```
Node newNode = new Node(aData,firstNode);
firstNode = newNode;
```

This will make your new node the head of the linked list, having as its next element the previous head of the list.

**UPDATE:**
Also, another problem is that `numberOfEntries` is always 0, since you do not increment it when you add the very first node. So, add a `numberOfEntries++;` inside the `else` block of the `add()` method, or just move the one that exists in the `if` block, outside the block.

Comment: Than you for helping me find that mistake, however that did not fix the issue that I am having

Comment: @Justin if the updated answer solved your problem, you can mark it as accepted. Otherwise, please let us know if you have further problems with what I suggested, so that we can fix them :)